# httplib vs urllib2 and cookies

Tags: python, http, cookies, urllib2, httplib

I like `urllib2` for automated routine operations, like cookie handling (with `cookielib.CookieJar`) or redirects processing. But i also like `httplib` for the low-level control that programmer have. For example, with `httplib` i can control for the order of HTTP headers but with `urllib2` i cannot. Also, with `httplib` i can easily set `Content-Type` header to whatever i need and send, but not with `urllib2` - it takes too much control over headers for itself and may rewrite my headers by its internal logic.

I would stay with `httplib`, but cookies processing with `httplib` is not very easy task. I can't connect it to `cookielib` and cookies parsing and processing is not so simple task to be done in 20 minutes with developing my own cookie-handling class.

Is there any cookies-processing solution standard for `httplib`?

Is there a way to control over order of headers to be sent with `urllib2` and turn off its intellect that may add new headers?

Comment: i prefer [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: actualy i've done http requests using js,java,groovy,python(urllib2 and requests) and i believe requests is the best by far. very easy to use and decent documentation.

Comment: @FooBarUser does it allows you to control over headers order? Does it support cookies?

Comment: [cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) for headers i know it takes a dict as an arg, i believe if you pass ordereddict it will work in order but i've never tried it.

Comment: if you tried requests and it doesn't work for headers order can you please post back? i will raise an issue in github if it doesn't work. thank you.

Comment: @FooBarUser my choise is `httplib` + `import Cookie`.

Comment: thank you for the reply i just thought if you tried and didnt work we could contribute to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass headers to httplib.

```
import httplib
headers = {"Cookie": "foobar",
           "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("example.org")
conn.request("GET", "", "", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
conn.close()
```

You could still use Cookielib for managing them.

Comment: cookies should be key-value pairs.